# How do I use GNU parallel retries feature without passing any parameters?

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I like the feature

```
parallel -q --retries 5 ./myprogram
```

But GNU parallel doesn't seem to work unless I pass it a set of args. So I have do something like this

```
seq 1 | parallel -q --retries 5 ./myprogram
```

Is there a way to tell GNU Parallel I don't want to pass it args, and just want to use it as a wrapper for retries?

Is there a bash way to do retries 5 without doing a bash for loop testing exit code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clearly know you are abusing GNU Parallel :) and thus should not be surprised if there is no elegant way of doing it.

One way to do it is to use -N0

```
parallel -N0 -q --retries 5 ./myprogram ::: dummy
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, from here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/471419:

```
parallel -q --retries 5 ::: ./myprogram
```